# Is the designation "chemical reaction" right for vibrational and electronic excitation of particles?

Tags: atomic-physics, terminology, physical-chemistry

I'm currently doing my Master's thesis, which focuses on Atmosphere Reentry Thermodynamics and Kinetics. Due to the importance of this work, I would like to use the best terms to describe any particular subject, that the thesis would bring. One of them is the vibrational and electronic excitation of particles. I don't know if I should call them "chemical reactions", because in these ones, a species  doesn't transform into another one, there's no chemical bond breaking neither a exchange of electrons. The only thing that changes is the electronic or vibrational level of the species. But it can be written as a chemical equation. For example, the spontaneous emission of molecular nitrogen from the excited electronic level A, and vibrational level $v'$, to the fundamental electronic level X, and vibrational level $v''$, is usually expressed as:

$$\text{N}_2(\text{A},v')\rightarrow N_2(\text{X},v'')+h\nu$$

where $h\nu$ represents a photon of energy $E=h\nu$.

Can I, for example, simply use the term "reaction" instead of "chemical reaction"? It is more general, and at least doesn't mention the more restrictive part, "chemical".

Comment: It sounds like 'emission' or 'decay' would be a good description of the process, though 'reaction' would be ok too, it seems. But I'm curious about this example. It seems nitrogen starts at a fundamental level and goes to an excited state emitting a photon. Shouldn't it be the other way around (go from excited to fundamental by emission)? (I'm not familiar with vibrational levels of atoms)

Comment: You're right. It should be the opposite. I will correct the equation.